# loading overlay close before navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

why does iOS reset the overlay when navigating and only after
this goes to another screen

why does iOS reset the overlay when navigating and only after
this goes to another screen

how to fix this bug in reit native,
1 overlay starts
2 an api request is made
3 and if everything is successful, then we send it to another screen

but iOS first turns off the overlay, showing the same screen (you can press the buttons)
and then redirects to the next screen

Android working as expected, overlay still working and navigate next screen